# AngularJS grid with heatmap

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, angularjs, heatmap

I am looking for a FOSS AngularJS grid, as full featured as possible.

But the main feature is that I would like some heatmap like colo(u)ring of the individual cells of the grid.

Smaller numbers should look "colder" and higher values should look "warmer".

Other than that, the only other must have" is export to CSV (although export to PDF would be a bonus).

Nice to have - as many features as possible, such as search, clicking a column title to sort, dragging columns to rearrange, etc.

Must be gratis, for commercial use.

[image]

---

[Update] is occurs to me that I could use a standard grid, which has an `OnDraw()` event for each cell, to return the background colo(u), or possibly even a `GetCssClass()` which is called for each cell.